# How to Resolve Page Redirect issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I click on href the dashboard page is loaded but the the location on the href is a different page.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>folder/controller/function">Add supplier</a></li>
```

**Controller**

```
public function add_supplier($id = null)
    {
        $this->tbl_supplier('supplier_id');

        if ($id) {//condition check
            $result = $this->global_model->get_by(array('supplier_id' => $id), true);

            if ($result) {
                $data['supplier'] = $result;
            } else {
                //msg
                $type = 'error';
                $message = 'Sorry, No Record Found!';
                set_message($type, $message);
                redirect('admin/purchase/manage_supplier');
            }
        }

        // view page
        $data['title'] = 'Add New Supplier';
        //$data['editor'] = $this->data;
        $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/purchase/add_supplier', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have exactly this code `<?php echo base_url() ?>folder/controller/function` in your view?

Comment: Yes exactly this one in  my view file i am trying other method for redirection but still facing same issue with that

Comment: That's why it is not working. You need to put exactly your controller and method name in your href: `<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>folder/your_controller_name/add_supplier">Add supplier</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url("folder/controller/function") ?>">Add supplier</a></li>
```

Passing the path into the site_url() helper function will return the correct path what are you looking for.

Comment: All the URL are working with base_URL but one of them among <li> tag is not working though it also uses base URL

Comment: can you share your config.php file to see more details?